# grpc: all calls are cancelling without intending to

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, grpc

I'm writing 2 WPF .Net Framework applications and have various protos, clients and implementations ready to use.

**The problem:**

App 1 sends first request (startup routine for App 2).

App 2 receives, handles, creates object to return, returns it.

App 3 throws Grpc.Core.RpcException: {"Status(StatusCode=Cancelled, Detail=\"Cancelled\")"}

I got the desired output, didn't set a timeout, and gave no cancellation token to even be called.

My channel is setup as follows, with 127.0.0.1 and 50052 as IP and Port.

```
_channel = new Channel($"{MyIP}:{MyPort}, ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
```

My server is setup by new'ing it up, iteratively adding services, then adding a port as:

```
_server.Ports.Add(new ServerPort({MyIP}, {MyPort}, 
    ServerCredentials.Insecure));
```

protos were compiled using grpc's auto compile methods, with `syntax="proto3". I'll add a snippet below.

```
service Hardware
{
    // A Simple RPC.
    //
    // Request for the hardware to initialise.
    //
    // Returns the state in an enum.
    rpc Initialise(StateChangeRequest) returns (State) {}
}

// Requests the change, with context coming from the command being sent.
message StateChangeRequest
{

}

// Returns the state enum, showing the different states of the hardware.
message State
{
    enum Status {
        UNKNOWN = 0;
        INITIALISED = 1;
        INITFAILED = 2;

    }

    Status status = 1;
}
```

The call is made as follows:

```
public async Task<bool> Initialise()
{
    try
    {
        // Initialise hardware via client.
        if (await _client.InitialiseAsync() != State.Types.Status.Initialised)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error(ex);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Any further information I can think of that may help:
Target Framework is                          `.NET Framework 4.6.2`
The `Google Protobuf` version I'm using is     `3.9.1.0`
The `Grpc Core version` I'm using is           `2.0.0.0`
The `Grpc Core Api` version I'm using is       `2.0.0.0`
These versions are identical in all projects used.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Apologies for the formatting and syntax errors. First SO post. It definitely builds!

Comment: While I don't have experience with the WPF and Grpc, I have experience with RPC technology (C,Java) and client/server/web and don't understand the question (yet).  Please state the behavior your are expecting and then the exception/error your are seeing as that might help me understand the question.  You do, however, show code and explain some things.  My best guess is that App2 and App3 are able to get messages, App2 gets and responds and App3 receives an exception because App2 has already processed the message.  All of this is a guess based on other work I've done.